# what should I select for learning state management in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have gone through provider for a basic,

but now want to go deep dive in state management ...so what should I select

```
PROVIDER, RIVER POD, GETX OR ANY OTHER?
```

I tried to learn river pod but gone confused as some teaching riverpod, some flutter river pod and some with hook river pod....cant figure out what differences between them...

so suggest me what should I follow....

I am learning for doing a job in future...

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are new to Flutter then learn Provider first. And then you can learn Bloc and RiverPod

Comment: Off-topic please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know that provider is the recommended package for state management by google and it depends on MVC design pattern. Still, actually I prefer Bloc over provider because it's the modified version of provider which depends on MVVM design pattern, MVVM design pattern when stands for Model View View Model is the dominant design pattern in android development. Hence, Bloc is more modern than provider but now they both perfect for state management even though many companies out there use provider as well as bloc.

according to your question you don't know what state management the company you're applying for is used so I think you should just understand the concept then you can learn whatever state management out there for work but for now provider is fine.

hope this help